# Difference - executing a unix command through java and through prompt i.e normal execution

Tags: java, unix, rsync

Could you please help me to resolve this issue.

I have a Java code which runs the rsync command using Runtime object.

I am running the below code at source machine, If there is any rsync connectivity problem during sync at target machine, the code should receive exit value, but that is not happening now.

```
String rsyncCommand = "rsync –abv  <source>  <remoteAddr:dest>"
Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime (); 
rt.exec(rsyncCommand);
```

To give you more details:

When I run the rsync command directly(not through java code) in source machine and if I kill the rsync process at target machine using kill -9 option during sync, the rsync process at source will exit with exit message.

But if I run the rsync through my java code and if I kill the process during the sync at target, it is not receiving any exit message.  The java and rsync process are still in running mode. But not doing any tasks.

What is the difference in running the command through java and directly through command prompt?

Any one has similar kind of problem with rsync, do we have any other options to run the rsync through java, I tried with “ProcessBuilder” as well.

Please provide me some pointers to solve this issue.

---

Thanks for the response, i gave only sample code, below is the complete code which i am using in my java.

```
 Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
  Process proc = null; 
  try { 
   proc = rt.exec(rsyncCommand); 
   InputStream stderr = proc.getErrorStream();
   InputStreamReader isrErr = new InputStreamReader(stderr); 
   BufferedReader brErr = new BufferedReader(isrErr);

InputStream stdout = proc.getInputStream();
InputStreamReader isrStd = new InputStreamReader(stdout);
BufferedReader brStd = new BufferedReader(isrStd);

String val = null;
while ((val = brStd.readLine()) != null) {
    System.out.println(val);
}

while ((val = brErr.readLine()) != null) {
    System.out.println(val);
}
int exitVal = proc.waitFor();
} catch (Exception e) {
e.printStackTrace();
```

}

Answer (score 2):

if you do this and the process is not finished yet you will not receive exit value

```
Process process = rt.exec(rsyncCommand);
int exitValue = process.exitValue();
```

instead you should use

```
int exitValue = process.waitFor()
```

then the thread will wait until the process returns exit value

Comment: Good point. I've updated my answer. Also, I've added handling for the `InterruptedException` that can be thrown by `waitFor()`.

Answer (score 1):

Your invocation of exec() is incorrect, it should specify the parameters directly, something like:

```
Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime (); 
rt.exec(new String[]{"rsync", "-abv", "<source>", "<remoteAddr:dest>"});
```

exec doesn't do any parsing of the command line, so it's trying to exec a command called "rsync –abv    " (as a single string)

Comment: assuming that source and remoteAddr and dest are input parameters to the function he may want to discard any `;` as you could do something like this: dest = "8080; rm -rf /"